# Android view with multi-directional swipe gestures

Tags: android, swipe

I have a view with a `TextView` containing long text, so the view has to give the user the facility of scrolling through the text.

Also, this `TextView` must allow swipe right and left on all instances of the view.

I've got the scroll working with `scollingMovementMethod` but the left and right swipe doesn't work.

Comment: by swipe of text view what you want to do? if you want to call next text on swipe then user pager control for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For enabling swipe gesture **left,right,up or down,** follow the below **steps**:

**Step 1:** Create a java file **SimpleGestureFilter**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

/**
* Created by nihal on 1/21/2016.
*/
public class SimpleGestureFilter extends  
 GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
public final static int SWIPE_UP= 1;
public final static int SWIPE_DOWN= 2;
public final static int SWIPE_LEFT= 3;
public final static int SWIPE_RIGHT = 4;
public final static int MODE_TRANSPARENT = 0;
public final static int MODE_SOLID= 1;
public final static int MODE_DYNAMIC= 2;
private final static int ACTION_FAKE = -13; //just an unlikely number
private int swipe_Min_Distance = 100;
private int swipe_Max_Distance = 350;
private int swipe_Min_Velocity = 100;
private int mode = MODE_DYNAMIC;
private boolean running = true;
private boolean tapIndicator = false;
private Activity context;
private GestureDetector detector;
private SimpleGestureListener listener;
public SimpleGestureFilter(Activity context,SimpleGestureListener sgl) {

    this.context = context;
    this.detector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
    this.listener = sgl;
}
public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

    if(!this.running)
        return;

    boolean result = this.detector.onTouchEvent(event);

    if(this.mode == MODE_SOLID)
        event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
    else if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) {

        if(event.getAction() == ACTION_FAKE)
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
        else if (result)
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
        else if(this.tapIndicator){
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
            this.tapIndicator = false;
        }

    }
    //else just do nothing, it's Transparent
}
public void setMode(int m){
    this.mode = m;
}
public int getMode(){
    return this.mode;
}
public void setEnabled(boolean status){
    this.running = status;
}
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                       float velocityY) {

    try {
        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
            return false;
        }
        // right to left swipe
        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) { // right to left
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_LEFT);



        }if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) { // right to left
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_RIGHT);



        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) { //    bottom to up
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_UP);



        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    this.tapIndicator = true;
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg0) {
    this.listener.onDoubleTap();;
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg0) {

    if(this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC){// we owe an ACTION_UP, so we fake an      
        arg0.setAction(ACTION_FAKE);//action which will be converted to an ACTION_UP later.                                   
        this.context.dispatchTouchEvent(arg0);
    }
    return false;
}

public interface SimpleGestureListener{
    void onSwipe(int direction);
    void onDoubleTap();
}

}
```

**Step 2:** Extend **AppCompatActivity** and implement **SimpleGestureFilter.SimpleGestureListener** in your Activity like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     
SimpleGestureFilter.SimpleGestureListener {
     //inside of activity, code here
  }
```

**Step 3:** define

```
private SimpleGestureFilter detector;
```

**Step4:** in your **onCreate** method add this:

```
detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
```

now **YourActivity** should look like this

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements    

SimpleGestureFilter.SimpleGestureListener {

private SimpleGestureFilter detector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
    detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);

}

 // add codes for Swipe Gesture here


 }
```

**Step 5:** Add codes for **Swipe Gesture** in **YourActivity**

```
public class sources extends AppCompatActivity implements 
SimpleGestureFilter.SimpleGestureListener {

private SimpleGestureFilter detector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sources);
    detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);

}



@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){

    this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);

}
@Override

public void onSwipe(int direction) {
    String str = "";



    switch (direction) {

        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT :

            //**code** here for what you wanna do with **Right Swipe**

        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT :
           //**code** here for what you wanna do with **Left Swipe**


        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN :

            break;

        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP :

            break;

    }



}




@Override

public void onDoubleTap() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Try swiping left", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

**Follow all the above steps correctly, you will be able to make swipe gestures work**